# How to return said value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have the following array:

```
var Boletins = [
{
    id:1, items:
    [
        {
            "#": "1",
            "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
            "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
            "Niveis": "muito elevados",
            "PoleneArvore": "cipreste, pinheiro",
            "PoleneErva": "urtiga, gramíneas"
        },
        {
            "#": "2",
            "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
            "Região": "região de Entre Douro e Minho",
            "Niveis": "muito elevados",
            "PoleneArvore": "plátano, pinheiro, carvalhos, cipreste",
            "PoleneErva": "urtiga"
        }]}];
```

And the following loop to select the "Data" field:

```
const data = Boletins.filter(x => x.id === 1).flatMap(data => data.items);

data.forEach(x => {
    window.alert(x["Data"]);
});
```

As you can see, both "Data" fields are the same and my loop returns me both fields. My question is, how can I change it in order for it to just return the first "Data" value from `id:1, items` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take first element of items after filter `data.items?.[0]`.

```js
var boletins = [
  {
    id: 1, items:
      [
        {
          "#": "1",
          "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
          "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
          "Niveis": "muito elevados",
          "PoleneArvore": "cipreste, pinheiro",
          "PoleneErva": "urtiga, gramíneas"
        },
        {
          "#": "2",
          "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
          "Região": "região de Entre Douro e Minho",
          "Niveis": "muito elevados",
          "PoleneArvore": "plátano, pinheiro, carvalhos, cipreste",
          "PoleneErva": "urtiga"
        }]
  }
];

const data = boletins.filter(x => x.id === 1).flatMap(data => data.items?.[0]);

data.forEach(x => {
  console.log(x.Data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An ID is an unique identifier. It doesn't make sense to filter for an ID. There should be only one element with this ID.

```js
var Boletins = [
{
    id:1, items:
    [
        {
            "#": "1",
            "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
            "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
            "Niveis": "muito elevados",
            "PoleneArvore": "cipreste, pinheiro",
            "PoleneErva": "urtiga, gramíneas"
        },
        {
            "#": "2",
            "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
            "Região": "região de Entre Douro e Minho",
            "Niveis": "muito elevados",
            "PoleneArvore": "plátano, pinheiro, carvalhos, cipreste",
            "PoleneErva": "urtiga"
        }]}];

const data = Boletins.find(x => x.id === 1)?.items[0];

if (data) {
    window.alert(data.Data);
}
```

Assuming all items have a `Data` property (otherwise your code would cause error message) you are looking for the first item in `items`. You can access it with `items[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = Boletins.filter(x => x.id === 1).flatMap(data => data.items);
```

Change it to this

```
var data = Boletins.flatMap(data => data.items).filter(x=> x["#"] === "1")
```